# What needs to happen to this: Ca5(PO4)3Cl to get this: CaCl2?

Tags: purification, minerals

$\ce{Ca5(PO4)3Cl}$ is a mineral called [Chlorapatite](http://www.mindat.org/min-1013.html)

So lets say I have some chlorapatite in my garage, what do I need to do to it so that I am left with Calcium Chloride $\ce{CaCl2}$?

Comment: Probably decompose it.